# How to render a graph with negative axis values within a frame style

Tags: pstricks

[image]

```
\psset{llx=-1cm, lly=-1cm, xAxisLabel=Time, yAxisLabel=Data, xAxisLabelPos={c,-1.4in}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.6in,c}}
%\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame, Dx=2.5, Dy=1](0,-1)(20,1){4in}{2in}
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame, Dx=2.5, Dy=1](0,0)(0,-1)(20,1){4in}{2in}
    \psline[linecolor=red](0, 0)(20, 0)
\end{psgraph}
```

I am attempting to render a graph that plots data over time. The data can be positive or negative. The script above renders a graph with the x-axis through the center of the frame, how do I render the x-axis to align with the bottom of the frame?

Note: My commented out line does not specify an origin. When I do this, my y-axis labels range from [0,2] instead of [-1,1] but it does render my x-axis at the bottom of the frame. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame, Dx=2.5, Oy=-1](0,-1)(0,-1)(20,1){4in}{2in}
```

Important is the first `(0,-1)` and `Oy=-1`

Comment: I have noticed that when we use `Oy` different from `0`, the axis line change its position, but if I want to put a x tick with `\psxTick` it appears correctly for `x` but at `y=0`.